# Is there a way to know when an option has been selected in Select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using the jQuery plugin [select2](https://select2.org/) (V4) and I want to change the border color when an option has been selected -- that would be on this class:

```
.select2-selection--single
```

However looking at the class changes et al when an option is selected it doesn't appear there is any solid way of knowing this within CSS; the only thing I really noticed was the addition of a `select2-container--below` class to the main select2 container, however I don't think using this would be wise as it doesn't appear to be meant for that.

Is there an easy way to achieve this or would I have to add this functionality myself?

Comment: The plugin api has all sorts of events to hook into

Comment: Have you checked templating both Dropdown and Selection (see https://select2.org/dropdown)?

Comment: However, check my fiddle if can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/0573357j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using both templating and Select2 CSS customization.

For example, to apply a custom style to elements selected in the dropdown:

```
li[aria-selected="true"] {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Use [Dropdown template](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) to format items in dropdown list and [Selection template](https://select2.org/selections#templating) to format elements selected.

Here is a code sample using those techniques: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/0573357j/

Comment: Thanks for the technique. I have used templates before with select2 but ended up just listening for their `select2:select` event and then changing the border color based off of that.

Comment: You can also change style of container in `templateResult` function, defined like this: `function formatStateDropdown (state, container)`. Fiddle updated.